# php.ini warning page has more than 1000 fields

Tags: php

After reaching so many entries PhpMyAdmin started showing this warning:

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. On submission, >some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars >configuration.

I have tried to change out the field from 1000 to 10000, then restarted php.ini.

> [ ok ] Restarting php7.0-fpm (via systemctl): php7.0-fpm.service.
>   /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart

Nothing seems to work so I can export mysql database. Please help me get this correct so I can get this database exported. Many thanks.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` to ensure that you're editing the right `php.ini` file and that your setting has taken effect.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found.

First of, be sure that you are editing the right `php.ini` file. To do that you can check what it is with `phpinfo()`.

Then restart php to reload `php.ini`, depending on how you installed it, it could be done like that :

`brew services restart php72`

Restart apache as well to be sure :

`sudo apachectl -k restart`

Then put the following statement in a test.php file :

`echo ini_get('max_input_vars');` and check it.

At this point you will see it is correctly updated.

If you still have phpmyadmin showing error after that, you should then hard refresh your phpmyadmin page : it can be done with `CMD+SHIFT+R` on a Mac.

The reason for this is that phpmyadmin's local javascript file is gettting passed the value of `max_input_vars` from php and is responsible for deciding to display the error or not. So if the javascript local file isn't updated for caching reasons for example, then you just have to refresh it and problem gone : )